Will the editor of the issue handle the paper?
I have a question about the handling process for submitting paper to an issue
Will the editor that handle the paper be the the editor of the journal or the issue ?
the statuses are

submitting the paper
got major revisions
submitting the revisions
but got Editor Assigned for two days then Editor invited


Do you mean a special issue, or a normal one?

yes , special issue

Usually for special issues the guest editor(s) of the special issue handles the paper.
Exceptions apply, e.g. if the guest editor submits a paper to their own special issue, then someone else (usually a member of the journal's editorial board) will take over.

I’ve been involved in organising special issues twice; once for a Wiley journal and once for an Elsevier journal. In both cases, there was a team of guest editors handling the issue, and a managing editor assigned to handle the special issue overall. In one case, the managing editor was one of the guest editors who proposed the special issue. In the other case, the managing editor was one of the journal’s regular Associate Editors who was assigned to work with the guest editors.
The steps in both cases were:

Authors submitted papers, tagging the paper as intended for the special issue.
Journal staff or the Chief Editor assigned the paper to the Managing Editor for the special issue (or to one of the other guest editors if there was a conflict of interest, such as a paper submitted from the managing editor’s own research group).
The Managing Editor read the paper and (unless she decided to desk-reject it) assigned the paper to a guest editor (or else handled it herself).
The guest editor or managing editor read the paper, found reviewers, read the reviews when they came in, and made a recommendation (accept, revise or reject).
The Managing Editor read the reviews and the guest editor’s comments, ratified the decision, and notified the authors.
When a revised version of the paper was submitted, the process was repeated, with the same guest editor selected to handle the revision unless unavailable.

This is essentially the same process as for regular issues, but with a Managing Editor in place of a senior Editor and a Guest Editor in place of an Associate Editor.
I’ve also been asked to edit special issues for MDPI journals, who proposed a different approach: in this case, the guest editor’s main role was to propose a theme and solicit papers for a special issue, while journal staff would find reviewers and make recommendations. (I declined these requests).
